# Offcanvas Sidebar With Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

[image: Offcanvas Sidebar]

**My goal:**

Using Boostrap 3, create a sidebar menu with independent scrolling.  The toggle button needs to be in the fixed nav header.  [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) has the exact behavior I'm looking for.  I'd prefer to do this without the use of plugins.

**Things I've tried:**

- [Jansy Bootstrap Offcanvas Reveal Sidebar](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/)

  - *Main Issue*: on menu toggle, the page always scrolls to the top.  I need it to NOT scroll 

    [image: jansy bootstrap]

- [Bootstrap Offcanvas Example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/)

  - *Main Issue*: On menu toggle, the menu doesn't always show.  I need it to automatically it's top value so it shows under the fixed nav 

    [image: Toggle Nav]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve that without any plugins, you can customize it for your needs:

CSS:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.off-canvas {
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #333;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1060;
}
.off-canvas-active .off-canvas {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  padding-top: 50px;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.off-canvas-active .page-wrapper,
.off-canvas-active .navbar-fixed-top {
  transform: translateX(300px);
}
.list-group {
  padding: 20px;
}
.off-canvas-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  z-index: 1050;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.off-canvas-active .off-canvas-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

JS:

```
// Toggle on button click
$('.off-canvas-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('body').toggleClass('off-canvas-active');
});

// Close on mouseup and touchend
$(document).on('mouseup touchend', function(event) {
  var offCanvas = $('.off-canvas')
  if (!offCanvas.is(event.target) && offCanvas.has(event.target).length === 0) {
    $('body').removeClass('off-canvas-active')
  }
});
```

### [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/makshh/pen/BRvXdX)